# WPF RibbonGroup selection Changed Event

Tags: wpf, ribbon-control

Hi i'm wondering if someone can help me.

I'm using a WPF Ribbon control and specifically a RibbonGroup control within that. The xaml for the RibbonGroup that i am using is below.

```
        <r:RibbonGroup x:Name="ribbonGroup" Header="Ribbon Group" >
                <r:RibbonRadioButton Label="Item 1"  IsChecked="True"  />
                <r:RibbonRadioButton Label="Item 2"  />
                <r:RibbonRadioButton Label="Item 3"  />
            </r:RibbonGroup>
```

Now the issue i am having is how can i identify when a selectio is changed in this group. So if i selected Item 2 or Item 3 how can i be notifified which actual item is selected. Is there some sort of changed event on the RibbonGroup control that i can bind to ? I have looked on the web but not really had any luck i would mega appreciate it if anyone can point me in the correct direction.

Thanks
Iffy.

Answer (score 0):

You want to bind to the Checked event of the radio buttons. The Checked event is a routed event, so you can bind it in the RibbonGroup element itself:

```
    <r:RibbonGroup x:Name="ribbonGroup" Header="Ribbon Group" 
            RadioButton.Checked="YourEventHandler">
        <r:RibbonRadioButton Label="Item 1"  IsChecked="True"  />
        <r:RibbonRadioButton Label="Item 2"  />
        <r:RibbonRadioButton Label="Item 3"  />
    </r:RibbonGroup>
```

In the event handler the RoutedEventArgs.Source property is a reference to the radio button that was checked.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply. :) I did try that but i can't seem to access r:RibbonRadioButton.Checked it doesn't show up in intellisense. There are other contorls but not RibbonRadioButton. I actually found a work around. What i did was create a command and set the command on every RibbonRadioButton in my Group so they all execute the same command and in the command handler event that the command executes i just do what i need to do and the e.OriginalSource object is my radio button.

Comment: My apologies... the event is inherited from the stock RadioButton. See my edit.